# Mysql 5.7 - Incorrect Datetime - works with different date value

Tags: mysql, sql

on this table 'signup'

```
UPDATE `signup` SET `expirationdate` = '2022-03-13 03:00:39' WHERE `signup`.`UID` = 3
```

this query works, however

```
UPDATE `signup` SET `expirationdate` = '2022-03-13 02:00:39' WHERE `signup`.`UID` = 3
```

this one returns the following:

```
#1292 - Incorrect datetime value: '2022-03-13 02:00:39' for column 'expirationdate' at row 1
```

I'm trying to find an explanation to this, changing the hour to 3 doesn't return any errors.

**the type of the column 'expirationdate' is "timestamp"**

Comment: Sounds like a daylight saving time issue.

Comment: Check this: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/usa?year=2022

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, it works just fine for me...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS signup;

CREATE TABLE signup
(UID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,expirationdate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO signup VALUES (3,'2021-03-13 01:00:00');

UPDATE `signup` SET `expirationdate` = '2022-03-13 02:00:39' WHERE `signup`.`UID` = 3;

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

Edit: Following up on forpas's comment, my installation is a UK one, where the clocks change two weeks later, and one hour earlier...

Also, my installation is an old one, with default settings that probably differ from newer installations regarding the default handling of erroneous dates...

```
UPDATE `signup` SET `expirationdate` = '2022-03-27 01:00:39' WHERE `signup`.`UID` = 3;
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.02 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 1

SHOW WARNINGS;
```

> Invalid TIMESTAMP value in column 'expirationdate' at row 1

```
SELECT * FROM signup;
+-----+---------------------+
| UID | expirationdate      |
+-----+---------------------+
|   3 | 2022-03-27 02:00:00 |
+-----+---------------------+
```

Comment: this just made everything far more interesting :D

Comment: Do you have any triggers on this table?